# increment a counter by using links

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<% Integer i=(Integer)request.getAttribute("count"); %>
```

I want to increment/decrement my array counter(i) by pressing the link next/prev.
But so far it has not worked. I tried using script. My code is:

```
<form action="<%=application.getContextPath()%>/Controller" method="get" id="Form">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="prev" id="prev"></input>
<a class="button_prev" href="javascript:prev('<%=(i-1)%>')">prev</a>
</form>
```

The script code is:

```
function prev(i)
{
if(i==-1)
    i=0;
document.getElementById("prev").value=i;
request.setAttribute("count",i);
document.getElementById("Form").submit();
}
```

And my servlet code is:

```
Integer num=(Integer)request.getAttribute("chapter");
    if(num==1)
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Page2.jsp").forward(request, response);
    else if(num==2)
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Page3.jsp").forward(request, response);
    else if(num==3)
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Page4.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Could you please look through this and tell me what is wrong or could you tell me a better way to implement this??

My error is: Controller request is undefined.

My web-xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Website</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    com.tcs.website.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your Servlet URL mapping definition. Can you post the whole Servlet code?

Comment: Um this is my entire doGet method. Everything else i've done in the doPost method. You want to see that??

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking for the servlet configuration, this means, its name and url mapping on web.xml file or configuration using `@WebServlet` (depending how you developed it).

Comment: Is that it?? I'm quite new at this so not sure if this is what you asked for.. Sorry

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now, please post the generated HTML code when you run your page. You can see it when opening the page in a browser like FireFox or Chrome and pressing Ctrl + U.

Comment: He has several `request` variables (one at the JSP, other at the JavaScript and one at the Servlet). One of them is probably not properly defined. (I would stay and help more but I gotta sleep! Hope this comment helps!! cya!)

Comment: Um i'm not able to post the html tag..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up server side and client side code. Expression such as `<%=(i-1)%>` is evaluated on the server, and the variable i there will not be the same as the one on your javascript

You need to review your business requirements, where should the counter be stored? On the server / client side?

Comment: This is not the problem. Refer to bottom line on the question: *My error is: Controller request is undefined*.

Comment: The counter should be stored in the server side

Answer (score 0):

Form values are passed to servlet as request parameters.
You can simply get the values request.getParameter("prev");
You are assigning the value request.setAttribute(i); this is not required.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

`<form action="/Controller" method="get" id="Form">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="prev" id="prev"></input>
<a class="button_prev" href="javascript:prev()">prev</a>
</form>`

**Javascript Code**

```
`function prev(){`

`var i = parseInt(document.getElementById("prev").value)-1;
if(i==-1)i=0;
document.getElementById("prev").value=i;
document.getElementById("Form").submit();
}`
```

**Servlet code**

```
Integer num=Integer.valuesOf(request.getParameter("prev"));
if(num==1)
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Page2.jsp").forward(request, response);
else if(num==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you calling i an "array counter"?

2) Your servlet code retrieves a 'chapter' attribute, but there is no mention of 'chapter' in your html or javascript.

3) Your javascript code:

```
function prev(i)
{
    if(i==-1)
        i=0;

    document.getElementById("prev").value=i;
    request.setAttribute("count",i);
    document.getElementById("Form").submit();
}
```

...executes in a browser.  And code executing in a browser has no idea about what variables and methods exist on the server.  Likewise, a servlet executing on the server has no idea about what variables and methods exist in some javascript code executing in a browser.  So in your javascript code, what does the variable request refer to?

4) Below is a complete example you can try.  You have a lot of moving parts, and the paths for each component are governed by different rules.

The url to enter into your browser:

```
http://localhost:8181/myapp2/Go/fish/in/a/lake
```

(I've configured Tomcat to listen on port 8181)

Directory structure in Tomcat:

```
webapps/myapp2/
   js/
      jquery-1.9.1.js
      jquery-ui-1.10.2.js
      myjs.js
   jsp/
      Initial.jsp
      Page2.jsp
      Page3.jsp
   WEB-INF/
      web.xml
      classes/
         com/
            tcs/
               website/
                   Controller.class
```

web.xml-------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MySuperAwesomeController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tcs.website.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MySuperAwesomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Go/fish/in/a/lake</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

myjs.js----------------------------------------

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  var chapter_val = $("#chapter_div").text();
  chapter_val = parseInt(chapter_val);
  chapter_val = (--chapter_val < 0) ? 0 : chapter_val;

  alert("Assigning onclick handler to the link...\n" +
        "When the link is clicked, the onclick function \n" +
        "will change the link's url to include the chapter val => " + chapter_val);


  $(".button_prev").on("click", function() {
    this.href += "?chapter=" + chapter_val;
  });


});
```

Here is a pure javascript version (but you really should use jquery to avoid several potential problems):

```
window.onload = function () {

  var chapter_val = document.getElementById("chapter_div").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  chapter_val = parseInt(chapter_val);
  chapter_val = (--chapter_val < 0) ? 0 : chapter_val;

  alert("Assigning onclick handler to the link...\n" +
        "When the link is clicked, the onclick function \n" +
        "will change the link's url to include the chapter val => " + chapter_val);

  document.getElementsByClassName("button_prev")[0].onclick = function() {
    this.href += "?chapter=" + chapter_val;
  };

};
```

Controller.java------------------

```
package com.tcs.website;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                                throws IOException,
                                       ServletException {

        String chapter = req.getParameter("chapter");
        String jsp_path = null;

        if (chapter == null) {
            jsp_path = "/jsp/Initial.jsp";
        }
        else {
            int chapter_num = 0;

            try {
                chapter_num = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("chapter"));

                if ( (chapter_num == 3) || (chapter_num == 4) ) {
                     jsp_path = "/jsp/Page" + 
                                Integer.toString(--chapter_num) + 
                                ".jsp";
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Bad chapter number");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("*********jsp_path=" + jsp_path);  #goes to logs/catalina.out
        req.getRequestDispatcher(jsp_path).forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Initial.jsp----------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Initial.jsp</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/myjs.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="chapter_div">5</div>
  <a class="button_prev" 
     href="<%= application.getContextPath() %>/Go/fish/in/a/lake">prev</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Page2.jsp------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page2.jsp</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/myjs.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="chapter_div"><%= request.getParameter("chapter") %></div>
  <a class="button_prev" 
     href="<%= application.getContextPath() %>/Go/fish/in/a/lake">prev</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Page3.jsp------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page3.jsp</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myapp2/js/myjs.js'></script>


</head>
<body>

  <div id="chapter_div"><%= request.getParameter("chapter") %></div>
  <a class="button_prev" 
     href="<%= application.getContextPath() %>/Go/fish/in/a/lake">prev</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @user2411994, I posted a complete servlet example for you to look at.